# Numpy - Make all pixel on target image 0 where mask is 0

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray, tensor, torch

I am working on a computer vision problem, and in an image preprocessing part I encountered a problem that I can not solve.

Let's say I have a pair of images - `(image, mask)`.`image` is a 3 channel image with shape `(H,W,3)`, while `mask` is a 1 channel image with shape `(H,W,1)`.

What I'm trying to do is set all pixels on `image` to 0 in positions where `mask` is 0.
My first solution was using a double for loop and it worked.

```
for y in range(mask.shape[1]):
        for x in range(mask.shape[2]):
            if mask[:,y,x] == 0:
                img[y,x,:] = 0
```

- Don't be confused with different indexing, in this solution `img` is `torch.Tensor`, and I cast it all to `torch.Tensor` when I return from a function which this block is a part of

However, it's too slow when I'm training my models, my batch loading hangs.

My next solution was `np.logical_not`, but it returns an error due to different number of channels between `img` and `mask`.

```
img[np.logical_not(mask)] = 0
```

Results in

```
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 2; dimension is 3 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

I also tried

```
img[mask==0] = 0
```

Which results in the same error message as above.

How can I solve this without being too slow?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It works when mask shape is `(H,W)`. So

```
img[mask.squeeze()==0] = 0
```

or

```
img[mask[...,0]==0] = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can squeeze the last dimension of your mask, as proposed in the other answer, or you can also use `np.where` as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

H, W, C = 8, 8, 3
img = np.random.rand(H, W, C)
mask = np.all(img < 0.5, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
print(mask.shape)  # (8, 8, 1)

default = 0
img_masked = np.where(mask, default, img)
```

Plotting the result:

```py
import matpotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax_orig, ax_mask, ax_masked) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey=True)

ax_orig.set_title("Original")
ax_orig.imshow(img)

ax_mask.set_title("Mask")
ax_mask.imshow(mask, cmap="gray")

ax_masked.set_title("Masked")
ax_masked.imshow(img_masked)

plt.show()
```

[image: result]